# converting a dictionary of dictionary to string

Tags: c#, tostring

i have a dictionary of dictionaries:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<char, string>> myDict;
```

i'm trying to output its contents by overriding the to string method but i cant figure out how to convert it to string.

i tried:

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
foreach (Dictionary<string, Dictionary<char, string>> s in str)
{
    myDict.Append(s.Keys).Append(",").Append(s.Values);
}
```

this did not work

Comment: Considering stringTransition is not defined I suspect it does not work

Answer (score 3):

Your version tries printing `s.Keys` and `s.Values`, which are both collections. You can print them using a loop, but you could use [`string.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421(v=vs.110).aspx) twice instead:

```
public override string ToString() {
    return string.Join(
        ",",
        myDict.Select(
            p => string.Format(
                "{0}:{1}",
                p.Key,
                string.Join(",", p.Value.Select(x => string.Format("{0}={1}", x.Key, x.Value)))
        )
    );
}
```

**Note 1:** the above syntax uses [`string.Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), rather than [*string interpolation*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interpolated-strings), in both calls. If you are using a newer version of C#, you could rewrite it for a somewhat shorter code, for example

```
string.Join(",", p.Value.Select(x => $"{x.Key}={x.Value}"))
```

**Note 2:** For older versions of .NET add `ToArray()` after both selects:

```
return string.Join(
    ",",
    myDict.Select(
        p => string.Format(
            "{0}:{1}",
            p.Key,
            string.Join(",", p.Value.Select(x => string.Format("{0}={1}", x.Key, x.Value)).ToArray())
    ).ToArray()
));
```

Comment: @TSB_1020 Did you import `System.Linq` at the top of your C# file?

Comment: yes i did. the error message says: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string[]'

Comment: @TSB_1020 Are you on .NET 3.5 then? Add `ToArray()` call after both selects.

Comment: @TSB_1020 Please see the edit. [This compiles on mono](https://ideone.com/wiAblc).

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [`Newtonsoft.Json`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/), which supports serializing dictionaries to string.

```
var values = new Dictionary<string, IDictionary<char, string>>
{
    {
        "test", new Dictionary<char, string>
        {
            ['a'] = "apple",
            ['b'] = "banana",
            ['c'] = "cat"
        }
    },
    {
        "lights", new Dictionary<char, string>
        {
            ['c'] = "compact fluorescent",
            ['l'] = "light emitting diode",
            ['i'] = "incandescent"
        }
    }
};

Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(values));
```

Output:

> {"test":{"a":"apple","b":"banana","c":"cat"},"lights":{"c":"compact fluorescent","l":"light emitting diode","i":"incandescent"}}

Comment: Owww... .nice output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var s in myDict)
{
    foreach (var i in s.Value)
    {
        //Key is char, Value is string
        str.Append("(")
           .Append(s.Key)
           .Append(",")
           .Append(i.Key)
           .Append(",")
           .Append(i.Value)
           .Append("),");
    }
}
//remove trailing ","
var s = str.ToString().Trim(",");
```

Comment: this one is giving me an error on the 's' in the inner foreach loop

Comment: Oops... doing this from the top of my head... hold on

Comment: this worked but did not show the chars in Dictionary<string, Dictionary<char, string>>

Comment: In that case you can append the `i.Key` as well, I want sure how you wanted your output to be.

Comment: i wanted it to be somethng like (string, char, string), (string, char, string), ...

Comment: Here you are. Next time I will ask for the output first ;-)